# using a json array integer in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, d3.js

I want to import an json array of integers in a scope.data to use in peopling a d3 bars , but when It doesn't work ! it gets the array in scope.data beacause when I do {{data}} in the html it show the array but can't exploit it for the d3 bars , please help !!

```
 angular.module('myApp', [])
//.controller('SalesController', ['$scope', function($scope, $http){
.controller('SalesController', function($scope, $http) {

/* $http.get('js/todos2.json')
.then(function(res){

      $scope.data = res.data;              
});*/

/*$http({method: 'GET', url: 'js/todos2.json'}).success(function(data)
{
$scope.data = data; // response data 
});*/

$http.get('js/todos2.json').success(function(data) {
   $scope.data = data;
});

/*$scope.data = [Math.random(),12,6,8,15];*/
/*$scope.data = 7*/
$scope.text = ('klopm');
 //parseInt(data)
}).directive('bars', function ($parse) {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     replace: true,
     template: '<div id="chart"></div>',
     scope:{data: '=data'},
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
       var data = scope.data;
       function drawBars() {
          var chart = d3.select('#chart')
         .append("div").attr("class", "chart")
         .selectAll('div')
         .data(data[0]).enter()
         .append("div")
         .transition().ease("elastic") //had la ligne bantli zayda na9ssa b3da pr l'affichage il faut savoir a quoi sert
         .style("width", function(d) { return d + "%"; })
         .text(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
       }
       drawBars();

     } 
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get data from a **json** file, `$scope.data` won't get populated right away, you need to watch it to make sure it is populated before drawing your chart. In your directive definition, instead of just call `drawBars()` function right away, you need to make sure there is data. So something like this

```
scope.$watch('data', function(){
    if(!scope.data) return; //If there is no data, do nothing

    //now call your draw function
    drawBars();
})
```